# Añadir Sqlite para Dart 2.1

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy tratando de añadir un paquete a la instalación. Concretamente sqllite

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  test: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^2.0.1
  sqlite: any
```

Pub get me devuelve:

```
Because learnDart depends on sqlite any which requires SDK version >=1.8.3 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
exit code 1
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si revisas el package `sqlite` no es compatible con Dart 2.0 >= :

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqlite

Por lo tanto te recomiendo que uses el package `sqflite` que está constantemente actualizado, te dejo el link:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite

Y quedaría así :

```
    environment:
      sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'

    dependencies:
      test: ^1.0.0
      json_serializable: ^2.0.1
      sqflite: any
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es de gran ayuda